# Android referral is received only after user opens the app

Tags: android, campaign-monitor

Google states that it broadcasts the referrer on app install (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-how)

> 1. After the user downloads and installs your app, the Google Play Store will broadcast an INSTALL_REFERRER intent on the device that includes those same campaign parameters.
> 2. Your app will then respond to that intent, using the BroadcastReceiver object provided below, reading the campaign parameters and using them to update the Google Analytics campaign information.

But I am noticing that my app is getting the broadcast for the referral only after the user opens the app.

Am i doing something wrong \ is there any way to receive the referral broadcast before the user opens the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your app will receive broadcasts only once it has been opened, starting Android 3.1 for security reasons. On Android 3.0 and below, you will receive them regardless of whether or not your app has been opened.

There is no way around this.

Comment: @asafgitai http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols